# My GeoJson will not display on a Vector Layer in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I have geoJson from the the USGS that I am downloading to my server.

It validates just fine with geojsonlint.

When I past the JSON into [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html) Openlayers example it says it is bad input json.

My Code to display it on a vector layer is as follows where variable mapProjection is EPSG:900913.

I have spent 3 days on this now, and cannot get it do display. What am I doing wrong?

Added Information, I have tried this method:

```
vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("MyLayer");
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

function handler(request) {

var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
    'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
    'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
});

vectorLayer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(request.responseText));
}

var request = OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url: "geojson.json",
    callback: handler
});
```

and have been able to see the json in variable request in the handler function. It has to be something to do with the format of the data.

I am on a windows system and writing the data to a txt file, then serving it to my openlayers app via IIS. I have the correct mime types set up for json already.

```
    var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                'internalProjection': mapProjection,
                'externalProjection': wgs84
                });

var newlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
            layername, 
            {
            style: style_mark,
            projection: wgs84,                          
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP
                    ({
                            url: '/data/earthquake_day.json?' + forcedownload,
                            format: geojson_format
                    })
            }
    );
 map.addLayers([newlayer]);
```

This is the Geojson ..

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","metadata":{"generated":1382079580000,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson?%2053324","title":"USGS Magnitude 2.5+ Earthquakes, Past Day","status":200,"api":"1.0.11","count":21},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":4.9,"place":"69km WSW of Panguna, Papua New Guinea","time":1382072700910,"updated":1382074535000,"tz":600,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000kg7b","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/usb000kg7b.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":null,"sig":369,"net":"us","code":"b000kg7b","ids":",usb000kg7b,","sources":",us,","types":",cap,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","nst":null,"dmin":8.182,"rms":0.95,"gap":86,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 4.9 - 69km WSW of Panguna, Papua New Guinea"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[154.9386,-6.6267,38.4]},"id":"usb000kg7b"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":4.3,"place":"30km ESE of Jarm, Afghanistan","time":1382069641720,"updated":1382071013039,"tz":270,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000kg6q","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/usb000kg6q.geojson","felt":0,"cdi":1,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":null,"sig":284,"net":"us","code":"b000kg6q","ids":",usb000kg6q,","sources":",us,","types":",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","nst":null,"dmin":2.372,"rms":0.49,"gap":112,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 4.3 - 30km ESE of Jarm, Afghanistan"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[71.1215,36.7111,215.63]},"id":"usb000kg6q"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":4.4,"place":"37km ESE of Grande Anse, Guadeloupe","time":1382068917150,"updated":1382075936219,"tz":-240,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000kg6l","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/usb000kg6l.geojson","felt":1,"cdi":2,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":null,"sig":298,"net":"us","code":"b000kg6l","ids":",usb000kg6l,","sources":",us,","types":",cap,dyfi,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","nst":null,"dmin":0.927,"rms":1.03,"gap":187,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 4.4 - 37km ESE of Grande Anse, Guadeloupe"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-60.7685,16.1425,44.69]},"id":"usb000kg6l"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":4.8,"place":"59km ENE of Raoul Island, New Zealand","time":1382060352340,"updated":1382062761000,"tz":-720,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000kg5r","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/usb000kg5r.geojson","felt":0,"cdi":1,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":null,"sig":354,"net":"us","code":"b000kg5r","ids":",usb000kg5r,","sources":",us,","types":",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","nst":null,"dmin":0.547,"rms":1.24,"gap":109,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 4.8 - 59km ENE of Raoul Island, New Zealand"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-177.3712,-28.9952,68.09]},"id":"usb000kg5r"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":4.6,"place":"65km WSW of Manta, Ecuador","time":1382059956670,"updated":1382063766330,"tz":-300,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000kg5p","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/usb000kg5p.geojson","felt":3,"cdi":3.4,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":null,"sig":327,"net":"us","code":"b000kg5p","ids":",usb000kg5p,","sources":",us,","types":",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","nst":null,"dmin":3.14,"rms":0.76,"gap":105,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 4.6 - 65km WSW of Manta, Ecuador"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-81.3056,-1.0801,25.2]},"id":"usb000kg5p"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":4.9,"place":"Central Mid-Atlantic Ridge","time":1382059845140,"updated":1382060754000,"tz":-180,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000kg5q","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/usb000kg5q.geojson","felt":0,"cdi":1,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":null,"sig":369,"net":"us","code":"b000kg5q","ids":",usb000kg5q,","sources":",us,","types":",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,","nst":null,"dmin":13.904,"rms":1.17,"gap":79,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 4.9 - Central Mid-Atlantic Ridge"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-38.5333,7.9178,10]},"id":"usb000kg5q"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":3.1,"place":"114km N of San Juan, Puerto Rico","time":1382057000700,"updated":1382075958596,"tz":-240,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/pr13291001","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/pr13291001.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"REVIEWED","tsunami":null,"sig":148,"net":"pr","code":"13291001","ids":",pr13291001,","sources":",pr,","types":",cap,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,tectonic-summary,","nst":4,"dmin":1.23159025,"rms":0.21,"gap":306,"magType":"Md","type":"earthquake","title":"M 3.1 - 114km N of San Juan, Puerto Rico"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-66.0585,19.4955,15]},"id":"pr13291001"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":3.2,"place":"153km NNE of Vieques, Puerto Rico","time":1382056681300,"updated":1382074489829,"tz":-240,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/pr13291000","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/pr13291000.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"REVIEWED","tsunami":null,"sig":158,"net":"pr","code":"13291000","ids":",pr13291000,","sources":",pr,","types":",cap,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,tectonic-summary,","nst":6,"dmin":1.39957521,"rms":0.28,"gap":309.6,"magType":"Md","type":"earthquake","title":"M 3.2 - 153km NNE of Vieques, Puerto Rico"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-65.3018,19.7154,18]},"id":"pr13291000"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":2.9,"place":"61km NE of Camalu, Mexico","time":1382048867000,"updated":1382051103563,"tz":-420,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ci11379962","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/ci11379962.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"REVIEWED","tsunami":null,"sig":129,"net":"ci","code":"11379962","ids":",ci11379962,","sources":",ci,","types":",cap,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,scitech-link,tectonic-summary,","nst":3,"dmin":0.24254513,"rms":0.14,"gap":194.4,"magType":"Ml","type":"earthquake","title":"M 2.9 - 61km NE of Camalu, Mexico"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.6183,31.2453,6]},"id":"ci11379962"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":2.9,"place":"26km NE of Soledad, California","time":1382048604900,"updated":1382061371165,"tz":-420,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc72089726","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc72089726.geojson","felt":1,"cdi":1,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"AUTOMATIC","tsunami":null,"sig":129,"net":"nc","code":"72089726","ids":",nc72089726,","sources":",nc,","types":",dyfi,focal-mechanism,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,tectonic-summary,","nst":null,"dmin":0.04491576,"rms":0.14,"gap":43.2,"magType":"Md","type":"earthquake","title":"M 2.9 - 26km NE of Soledad, California"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-121.1617,36.6223,7.9]},"id":"nc72089726"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":4.9,"place":"Mid-Indian Ridge","time":1382040756270,"updated":1382069714445,"tz":300,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000kfvj","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/usb000kfvj.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":null,"sig":369,"net":"us","code":"b000kfvj","ids":",usb000kfvj,","sources":",us,","types":",cap,dyfi,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,","nst":null,"dmin":20.785,"rms":0.71,"gap":74,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 4.9 - Mid-Indian Ridge"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[69.0736,-23.117,10]},"id":"usb000kfvj"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":3.2,"place":"26km ESE of Cohoe, Alaska","time":1382037828000,"updated":1382066784427,"tz":-480,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ak10825881","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/ak10825881.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"AUTOMATIC","tsunami":null,"sig":158,"net":"ak","code":"10825881","ids":",ak10825881,","sources":",ak,","types":",dyfi,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,tectonic-summary,","nst":67,"dmin":0.40963177,"rms":0.68,"gap":72,"magType":"Ml","type":"earthquake","title":"M 3.2 - 26km ESE of Cohoe, Alaska"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-150.8756,60.258,64.3]},"id":"ak10825881"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":4.9,"place":"176km ENE of Hachinohe, Japan","time":1382028863680,"updated":1382057818725,"tz":600,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000kfnh","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/usb000kfnh.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":null,"sig":369,"net":"us","code":"b000kfnh","ids":",usb000kfnh,","sources":",us,","types":",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","nst":null,"dmin":1.191,"rms":1.37,"gap":175,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 4.9 - 176km ENE of Hachinohe, Japan"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[143.529,40.8559,31.69]},"id":"usb000kfnh"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":3.1,"place":"33km N of Fritz Creek, Alaska","time":1382027563000,"updated":1382056509941,"tz":-480,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ak10825772","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/ak10825772.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"AUTOMATIC","tsunami":null,"sig":148,"net":"ak","code":"10825772","ids":",ak10825772,","sources":",ak,","types":",dyfi,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,tectonic-summary,","nst":69,"dmin":0.31351203,"rms":0.87,"gap":86.4,"magType":"Ml","type":"earthquake","title":"M 3.1 - 33km N of Fritz Creek, Alaska"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-151.1942,60.0298,87.9]},"id":"ak10825772"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":3.6,"place":"14km ESE of Hyrum, Utah","time":1382026759900,"updated":1382079018263,"tz":-360,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/uu60041537","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/uu60041537.geojson","felt":190,"cdi":3.2,"mmi":3.25,"alert":null,"status":"REVIEWED","tsunami":null,"sig":260,"net":"uu","code":"60041537","ids":",uu60041537,","sources":",uu,","types":",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,shakemap,tectonic-summary,","nst":null,"dmin":0.07186522,"rms":0.14,"gap":57.6,"magType":"Ml","type":"earthquake","title":"M 3.6 - 14km ESE of Hyrum, Utah"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-111.6838,41.6033,11.4]},"id":"uu60041537"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":2.7,"place":"10km WNW of Shasta Lake, California","time":1382024460700,"updated":1382058287850,"tz":-420,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc72089531","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc72089531.geojson","felt":1,"cdi":2,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"AUTOMATIC","tsunami":null,"sig":112,"net":"nc","code":"72089531","ids":",nc72089531,","sources":",nc,","types":",dyfi,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,","nst":null,"dmin":0.06288207,"rms":0.13,"gap":90,"magType":"Ml","type":"earthquake","title":"M 2.7 - 10km WNW of Shasta Lake, California"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.4883,40.7127,22.4]},"id":"nc72089531"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":2.6,"place":"13km SSE of Volcano, Hawaii","time":1382022033300,"updated":1382022379514,"tz":-600,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/hv60578296","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/hv60578296.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"AUTOMATIC","tsunami":null,"sig":104,"net":"hv","code":"60578296","ids":",hv60578296,","sources":",hv,","types":",general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,","nst":null,"dmin":0.05389892,"rms":0.35,"gap":100.8,"magType":"Ml","type":"earthquake","title":"M 2.6 - 13km SSE of Volcano, Hawaii"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-155.1912,19.3207,1.8]},"id":"hv60578296"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":2.5,"place":"8km SSW of Volcano, Hawaii","time":1382019528300,"updated":1382055396752,"tz":-600,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/hv60578286","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/hv60578286.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"REVIEWED","tsunami":null,"sig":96,"net":"hv","code":"60578286","ids":",hv60578286,","sources":",hv,","types":",cap,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,","nst":null,"dmin":0.00898315,"rms":0.1,"gap":54,"magType":"Ml","type":"earthquake","title":"M 2.5 - 8km SSW of Volcano, Hawaii"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-155.2747,19.3675,31.6]},"id":"hv60578286"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":3.1,"place":"19km W of West Bishop, California","time":1382017510600,"updated":1382072572313,"tz":-420,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc72089491","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc72089491.geojson","felt":2,"cdi":2.7,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"AUTOMATIC","tsunami":null,"sig":148,"net":"nc","code":"72089491","ids":",nc72089491,","sources":",nc,","types":",dyfi,focal-mechanism,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,","nst":null,"dmin":0.06288207,"rms":0.05,"gap":108,"magType":"Md","type":"earthquake","title":"M 3.1 - 19km W of West Bishop, California"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-118.6773,37.3892,13.2]},"id":"nc72089491"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":5.4,"place":"22km SSE of Lata, Solomon Islands","time":1382008392050,"updated":1382037346800,"tz":660,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000kfhi","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/usb000kfhi.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":null,"sig":449,"net":"us","code":"b000kfhi","ids":",usb000kfhi,","sources":",us,","types":",cap,dyfi,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","nst":null,"dmin":6.06,"rms":0.99,"gap":59,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 5.4 - 22km SSE of Lata, Solomon Islands"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[165.9252,-10.8982,62.8]},"id":"usb000kfhi"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":4.2,"place":"131km S of Puerto El Triunfo, El Salvador","time":1381997360900,"updated":1382026310261,"tz":-360,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000kfgf","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/usb000kfgf.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":null,"sig":271,"net":"us","code":"b000kfgf","ids":",usb000kfgf,","sources":",us,","types":",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","nst":null,"dmin":1.708,"rms":1.35,"gap":184,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 4.2 - 131km S of Puerto El Triunfo, El Salvador"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-88.5719,12.0947,40.04]},"id":"usb000kfgf"}],"bbox":[-177.3712,-28.9952,1.8,165.9252,60.258,215.63]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this issue, because your GeoJSON data has Z coordinates.

By Default, OpenLayer's GeoJSON parser fails when it finds more than two coordinates (i.e X & Y).

To solve this issue, you must set the [GeoJSON.ignoreExtraDims](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON.ignoreExtraDims) parameter to true.

Here is a sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devdatta/HsVzp/) which shows the code in actions.

Comment: That did it. Wish I had asked three days ago

Comment: It's a stupid default, and isn't mentioned anywhere. I too had to spend a fair bit of time when I had faced this problem.

Comment: It looks like the extra dim is the depth. Have you figured out a way to get that piece of info by any chance?

Comment: I haven't been able to get that value. I feel that it would make an excellent question. Please post it as a new question.